# Modeling RESTful API

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, restful-architecture

I just start learning webapi and trying to implement a RESTful API. My problem is how to model it. I have an Account model:

```
public class Account: EntityBase<string>
{
    [JsonProperty("_rev")]
    public string Revision { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; } = "account";
    [JsonProperty("firstname")]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("lastname")]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("role")]
    public string Role { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("password")]
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("salt")]
    public string Salt { get; set; }
}
```

and the Account Controller. I want to register an account:

```
//POST api/Accounts/Register
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Register([FromBody]Account account)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        var result = accountsService.RegisterAccount(account);
        return Ok(result);
    }
```

and the login:

```
//POST api/Accounts/Login
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Login([FromBody]Account account)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        var result = accountsService.LoginAccount(account);
        return Ok(result);
    }
```

My problem is that I have to make two POST requests to the same controller with the same parameters (the account model). Is this correct? Do I need to make another model (e.g. User Model) and use another controller for the login?

PS I use Angular to make the requests to the api.
Thanx

Answer (score 0):

I can think of SOLID principle #1 that applies to your situation:

> 1. Single Responsibility: There should be only one reason to change a class.

If you stick `Account` with name and password information. What if I want to change account info? What about user info? These are two separate reasons.

So, I would definitely create a separate model that encapsulates a specific concern.